# Why are escaped characters read from database, using PHP, displaying as normal text on output during regular expression replace?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am trying to store regular expression search and substitution strings in a database.  At runtime, I read the database, placing the strings into arrays, and then use the PHP preg_replace() method to update large strings written by users with fixes that my client wants.

Here is a sample string pair I am using:

Search string: `/([^\r\n+])(\[url)/i`
Substitute string: `$1\n\n$2`

If I place the string in code like this:

`preg_replace("/([^\r\n]+)(\[url)/i", "$1\r\n\r\n$2", ProcessString);`

Everything works beautifully.  This finds instances of a bbCode tag "[url" that does not have a carriage-return/linefeed combination directly in front of it and places that in front of the "[url" tag.

However, when I run the code as I stated using strings from the database (MySql), the "\r\n\r\n" print literals instead of actually creating carriage-return line feeds.  The strings are displayed in a "textarea" tag in HTML.

I have looked at the difference between single and quoted strings and my problem would seem to be this, I am assuming?  Thinking that the problem is that the strings coming from the database or inserted into the array I'm looping through are created as single-quoted strings, I tried this:

`preg_replace($findKey, "{$replaceValue}", ProcessString);`

Where $replaceValue = the string '$1\r\n\r\n$2' (again, I am assuming that reading from the database and/or placing the value into an array (mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) is placing the string value into a single-quoted string and therefore the escaped characters are printing as literals instead of the characters the escaped characters actually represent.  However, this did not work.

Here is the code I'm using to insert into the database:

`INSERT INTO ISG_TCS_Replacements (FindPhrase, ReplacePhrase, ReplacementGroupID, Description, IsRegEx, IsActive, ProcessGroup, ProcessSequence)
VALUES ("/([^\\r\\n]+)(\\[url)/i","$1\\r\\n\\r\\n$2", 0, "Add a new line after [url] tags that are not on a new line currently.", 1, 1, 0, 1);`

The fields are varchar(100).

Comment: Have you tried doing a var_dump() on the string from the database? I'm inclined to think that the output from the database has been escaped. Edit: also, why have you put curly braces around your replacement value?

Comment: I will try the var_dump() and see what I get.  Also, the curly braces were for something I tried, thinking that if my problem was that the string variable was being seen as a single-quoted string, maybe embedding the variable in a double-quoted string would do something for me.  The way the code actually is, is like this: preg_replace($findKey, $replaceValue, ProcessString);

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `\r\n` escapes only work in double quoted strings.

```
print "\r\n";
```

Whereas your database usage is likely akin to:

```
$replaceValue = '\r\n';
print "{$replaceValue}";   // uses the literal character string
```

You are inserting your replacement string with single quotes into the DB. Otherwise you would get the the actual linebreaks back. Mysql does escape them while inserting, but you always get the original string data back.
Reading from a MySQL TEXT/CHAR column is no different than reading from files really. Check your database with mysqladmin, if you see the literal `\r\n` then there is your problem.

(A literal `'\r\n'` btw works in the regex, but not in the replacement string.)

---

Something else. `([^\r\n+])` is probably meant to be `([^\r\n]+)`. The quantifier must be outside of the character class.

Comment: I'm inserting into the database via SQL script, and using "\\r\\n", an escaped sequence in order to insert it into the database. The column, as well, is a varchar. Maybe that's it? Should I be using a different data type in the db? I have to admit, I come from the .Net world where dealing with strings seems to be much more straight-forward, but maybe that's my unlearned prejudice. Also, yeah, thanks for the regex comment, I typed it in wrong - should have copied it ;)

Comment: No you should just use `"\r\n"` before sending it into the database. The mysql_real_escape_string function does encode that once, but it sitll comes back normally. Maybe just add your actual INSERT code to the question, so we can have a look.

Comment: Added the sql for the inserts. And sorry, originally accidentally edited your comments instead of mine.  This is actually the first time I've ever even posted here.  Normally don't have issues I can't resolve myself :)

Comment: Ah ok. I can see two issues there. You probably enclosed the whole query in `'` single quotes in PHP. The SQL however uses `"` around the strings. This accidentally works with MySQL, but only when it doesn't run in `--ansi` compliant mode. You should use single quotes in the SQL query, but double quotes for PHPs mysql_query() most of the time. -- The `\\r\\n` double escaping is sometimes okay in this context, but I would avoid it. -- Please post the surrounding PHP code too. :)

Comment: No, the code that I'm inserting I insert straight into the query window in phpMyAdmin, no quotes to start off with.  Therefore, no surrounding PHP code.  The only thing I do with PHP is retrieve the data and do the replacements on the string passed to the object I'm using to process text.

Comment: Ah, that clears it up. Then the double escapes are really redundant. MySQL works a bit differently than MS SQL Server. It interprets `\n` back into a newline on INSERTing. (And I just downloaded ;) and tested with phpMyAdmin, it naturally does not transform the \\ two backslashes. So MySQL sees them, and converts the two backslashes into one, and leaves the `r` and `n` as-is.)

Comment: Also, if I don't escape the "\", I only get a "rn" in the database when I insert (again, from phpMyAdmin, not PHP code).  Should I maybe be using a MySql function to do the escapes automatically instead of manually myself?  Maybe there's some process in a MySql function that escapes things correctly.

Comment: Right, sorry - I realized after I typed that that really they were converted into carriage return line feeds when I didn't escape them.  this was yesterday when I went through that :)  So I need some way to escape them so they show as "\r\n" to my regex substitution, a double-quoted string, as a variable instead of hard-coded in my object.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do what in your setting. All that heaps of back and forth escaping got me confused now too :/

Comment: Anyway I think you should go try to use mysql_query() from within PHP. And show the final code (both inserting and query and preg_match usage). This will give a better overview of what is going on. You didn't pick the easiest example there :}